# How can we evaluate the predicted values using Scikit-Learn

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, scikit-learn

I am using AdaBoost Classifier to predict values I have. How can evaluate the accuracy of prediction model (I'd like to see how the accuracy of predicted values).

You can check an example here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#usage

I found two options : using confusion matrix

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(expected, y_1)
```

or using cross val score

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf_1, X_train, y_train)
print scores.mean()
```

There is also: AdaBoostClassifier.staged_score(X, y) AdaBoostClassifier.score(X, y)

So, I am little bit confused.

One last question: Should I use predict() or predict_proba().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the accuracy of the predication you can do:

```
print accuracy_score(expected, y_1)
```

If you want a few metrics, such as, precision, recall, f1-score you can get a classification report:

```
print classification_report(expected, y_1)
```

A confusion matrix will tell how many of the samples that were classified are classified according to which label. This will tell you if your classifier confuses some categories.

The functions to get these metrics are independent of the classification model you are using. (So you can easily test an SVM for example)

You should use `predict()` since this will give the labels of the classified samples. `predict_proba` will give the propability of a sample belonging to a category

I recommend reading a few of the documentation pages:

- [Classification report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)
- [Accuracy score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)
- [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)
- [Adaboost classifier in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)

Comment: Thanks ! Another question regarding GLM Model, when I use the same metrics, I got an error: "Can't handle mix of binary and continuous". Is it different from model to another ?

Comment: My guess is you are using a regression model and not a classification model. If you want a linear classifier look at SGD, or a linear SVM or perceptron. Have a look at this diagram: http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.be/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html to choose a good model.

Comment: I am trying to do a benchmarking between two models for my school project. regression model(GLM), and another classification Algorithm (AdaBoost). In order to discuss the both algorithms I need to compare the prediction accuracy (check GLM example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215010/problems-using-glm )

Comment: I think you are confusing regression and classification. With regression the output takes on a continues value and with classification it will take on a class label. 

These 2 type of problems have different metrics. Since one is dealing with continues data and the other with discrete data. For example you can't use a confusion matrix when doing regression. A metrics for regression is for example mean squared error

Comment: Great Explanation. In this case, how can I measure the accuracy in  regression models (where we have continues data). Should we discuss Residuals, variance, pearsona-chi .. (Chech this example: http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/r-lm-summary.html)

Comment: I haven't done a lot of regression myself, but since you are working with sci-kit learn, why not use the error metrics they provide ? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics

Maybe it also good to know that saying you want to measure the "accuracy" of a regression model isn't a good word choice. Accuracy is a classification metric and has a well defined formula. I think you mean that you want to measure the performance of your regression model. And this is done with metrics such as those you can find in the link above, or on the page you linked.

Comment: could you please guide me how to evaluate the predicted values if I don't have the labels?